# Macro sends a request from Excel to PowerPoint: code works on my computers, not on the user's computer

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

My code calls PowerPoint from Excel and creates a slide with the data from a spreadsheet. The code works on my computers, but a user gets an error 1004.

I have tried to use another code previously developed by others. This one: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba

For some reasons, this code again works on my computer, but not on user's. It results in System Error 400 on some tabs, but it works on 1 tab.

```
Sub CopyRangeToPresentationTot()
'Step 1: Declare your variables
  Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim SlideTitle As String
'Step 2: Open PowerPoint and create new presentation
  Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
  Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add
  PP.Visible = True
'Step 3: Add new slide as slide 1 and set focus to it
  Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
  PPSlide.Select
'Step 4: Copy the range as a picture
  Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("B2:F18").CopyPicture _
  Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
'Step 5: Paste the picture and adjust its position
  PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
  PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
  PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True

'Step 7: Memory Cleanup
  PP.Activate
  Set PPSlide = Nothing
  Set PPPres = Nothing
  Set PP = Nothing
End Sub
```

I expect that my code will create a slide with the range from Excel as a picture. A user runs into an 1004 error.

Comment: When reporting an error, it's useful to have the actual line where the error occurs, and the text of the error message.

Comment: I found out that the erorr is with CopyPicture of Range Class. It is 1004 error.

Comment: Are you and the other user on the same version of excel, and what is that version?

Comment: I have the latest version. Do you think the error might happen due to the older versions of MS package?

Comment: If anything I find `CopyPicture` is flakier in the latest version, not the other way around...

Comment: `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("B2:F18").CopyPicture _
  Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Range("B2:F18").CopyPicture _
  Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture` (but this second version is more reliable) so maybe try that

Comment: Copy and Paste operations often take longer than the VBA takes to run. Look up the three methods of pausing execution around the statement that raises the error: Wait, Sleep and looping DoEvents.